# bootstrap mobile display error

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set the navbar for mobile device...but my code maybe has some error,i don't how to fix it ...

I've looked up the getbootstrap.com and try some changes,still don't work,what should i do to modify my code to adjust the mobile device?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get issueed for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">hello world</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><%= link_to("往期",issues_path) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to("招聘",jobs_path) %></li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
              <% if !current_user %>
                  <li><%= link_to("註冊", new_user_registration_path) %> </li>
                  <li><%= link_to("登入", new_user_session_path) %></li>
                <% else %>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <%= gravatar_tag current_user.email, :size => 30, :default => "https://tower.im/assets/default_avatars/path.jpg"%>
                        Hi!, <%= current_user.email %>
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <li> <%= link_to("管理后台", admin_users_path) %> </li>
                      <li> <%= link_to("个人信息", account_user_path(current_user)) %> </li>
                      <li> <%= link_to("登出", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: First, you haven't even told us what the problem is...

Comment: Second, check your markup because it's not "bootstrap valid" (eg. navbar header should have a button with data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1", you put it in a DIV and outside navbar header)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try setting this in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you want a little more info on how this works check out this  [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: I had a similar set up with no luck on mobile in the past. Adding that to the head tag did the trick for me.

Comment: I'm confused, how on earth do you know what's wrong...?

Comment: If you do not set the instal-scale to 1 for bootstrap the mobile set up will not work as intended

Comment: That's not true, I've never used initial-scale, and my Bootstrap mobile navbar menus work fine.

Comment: Interesting. All I know is I had a similar problem and the code above solved it. I'll read into viewport a bit more and follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what's the "mobile display error", but your markup code isn't "bootstrap valid", so could be your problem is that when switch to mobile view, navbar doesn't collapse to mobile button menu.

Your HTML should be like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hello world</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to("往期",issues_path) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to("招聘",jobs_path) %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
              <% if !current_user %>
                  <li><%= link_to("註冊", new_user_registration_path) %> </li>
                  <li><%= link_to("登入", new_user_session_path) %></li>
                <% else %>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      <%= gravatar_tag current_user.email, :size => 30, :default => "https://tower.im/assets/default_avatars/path.jpg"%>
                        Hi!, <%= current_user.email %>
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <li> <%= link_to("管理后台", admin_users_path) %> </li>
                      <li> <%= link_to("个人信息", account_user_path(current_user)) %> </li>
                      <li> <%= link_to("登出", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %> </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This code show a navbar that correctly collapse to mobile button menu (I don't know your <%%> tagg content...

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atbrhyv1/)